# Eligibility to Invite Parent to Visit UK

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

I would like to invite again my mother to visit me in the UK. I already renewed my permit to stay in the UK, but my Philippine passport has expired.

Am I still eligible to invite my mother to come in the UK for a visit? Or do I need to renew my Philippine passport?

Comment: According to https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk your passport must be valid for the whole of your stay in the UK. I’m surprised you were able to renew your residence permit beyond the expiry date of your passport.

Comment: Renewing your passport definitely won’t **hurt**.

Comment: @Traveller That information is a simplification. I believe that page is mainly intended for visitors. Of course, residence permits can be issued beyond the length of the passport. That's part of the reason for switching from vignettes to residence permits: You no longer need to carry around an old passport with a visa and your new passport. It is unsurprising and very common for a passport to expire before the end of a residence permit.